# Apache server isn't starting on webmin

Tags: apache, webmin, virtualmin

I am running several php sites creating virtualmin in webmin. I use two ips (one is shared and another is dedicated) in that server. Suddenly all my sites became down as apache couldn't start.[dashboard of webmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akiwl.png)

another thing my shared ip is showing here.But i want to use dedicated ip to start the apache.
[status of apache surver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Ybo.png)

Comment: You're trying to use a port which is already in use. Usually 9001 is probably used by php-fpm

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Its not working with other ports too.

Comment: Are you sure that the dedicated ip address is actually assigned to an interface of your server? It's hard to provide an answer since the details you provide are quite limited. Try with a random port like 58781 and see if it works